# Maximum of the expectation of a concave function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, information-theory

Let's have a function $f(x, \theta)$, and some probability distribution on $x$. Let's say I have found $\theta^* = \operatorname{argmax}(f(E[x], \theta) $, and $f$ is concave in $x$. 
I would like to prove, that $E_x[f(\theta^*, x)] \ge E_x[f(\theta, x)] $, or in other words, for concave function $f$, is it true, that $E_x[f(x)]$ is maximized, when $f(E_x[x])$ is maximized.

I've been through Jensen's inequality, but I haven't been able to find a prove for this. 
I know that the distribution of $x$ is Rayleigh distribution.

Thanks a million !

Comment: concave in $x$ but not in $\theta$?

Comment: also concave in $\theta$. Does that help?